# Facebook Implementation within app (without opening in safari or native app)

Tags: iphone, facebook, safari, fbconnect

I have gone through the FBCOnnect sample code for iPhone downloaded from 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/
But it opens the facebook page in safari or on device the native app is opened and the app is switched in Background I dont want this to happen.Also the method callbacks like 
'- (void)fbDidLogin' is not called at all after login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Facebook iOS SDK, you can edit Facebook.m's authorize method and set safariAuth and authorizeWithFBAppAuth both to no so that it does the Facebook connect style popup login.