# Publishing images on Facebook iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I am making and app that you modify images and then you could upload it to Twitter, Facebook, etc... My problem it's with Facebook. also fbDidLogin never called. I Follow allot of tutorials to this and search allot and try allot of solutions and nothing.

Because i don't know if the user will export the photo to Facebook I login it only when its necessary I leave the code. I hope someone can help me.

What I need it's to publish my image that I create into the users wall

```
//<FBSessionDelegate, FBDialogDelegate, FBRequestDelegate>

- (void)publishFacebook:(UIImage *)img {

    [self loginFacebook];
    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        img, @"picture", @"Testing...", @"caption",
                                        nil];
    [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Image posted");
}

- (void)loginFacebook {

    if (_facebook == nil) {
        _facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:self];
    }

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        _facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        _facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if (![_facebook isSessionValid]) {
        NSArray *permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", @"offline_access", @"publish_stream", nil];
        [_facebook authorize:permissions];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
}

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[_facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[_facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}
```

And in my app delegate

```
// Pre 4.2 support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [[_viewController facebook] handleOpenURL:url]; 
}

// For 4.2+ support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [_viewController.facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

It go to the Facebook app, and it request all the permissions etc.. and IT said in the console "Image Published" but if I stay in Facebook app without accepting or declining, just stay there it execute the upload image...

If in the Facebook App I accept all the permissions it return to my normal app. The app Delegate methods are return normal values a webpage of Facebook with a really long string.

What could I do?

Thanks

Comment: @Emesto I really couldn't understand what you are trying to say..but i will try to help you with your code..Before that can you just look at my SO question... http://stackoverflow.com/q/9238700/1083859

Comment: @R.A hi men, I checkout the post and that its for publishing an image but with url, this its different because I got an UIImage that I want to upload and publish  in Facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code...

```
    -(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{ //start the facebook action by clicking any button
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"YOUR_APP_ID" andDelegate:self];

     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
                facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
                facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
            }
    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:nil];
    }else{
    [self postWall];
    }
    // Pre 4.2 support
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
        return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
    }
// after 4.2 support
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
    - (void)fbDidLogin {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        [self postWall];
    }
    -(void)postWall{

          NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Test message", @"message", imageData, @"source", nil];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];

        NSLog(@"Image posted");
    }
-(void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled{
    if (cancelled) {
        UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Could not Login" message:@"Facebook Cannot login for your application" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

Check out did you put delegate to FBsessionDelegate,FBRequestDelegate in your controller File.Try to run your facebook in your app itself and NOT in SAFARI.To do that check this link. [Facebook Implementation within app (without opening in safari or native app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280963/facebook-implementation-within-app-without-opening-in-safari-or-native-app)

**EDITED:**
Changed code with postWall method and added fbDidNotLoginMethod.This is the correct one.

Comment: i will check it , because what I need its to login and do everything inside the same function I test it and tell you thanks